# Prove $f'(\frac{x_1+2x_2}3)<1-a$ for two zeros $x_1<x_2$ of $f(x)=\ln x+x-ax^2$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

> Let $f(x) = \ln x + x - ax^2$, where $a > 0$. Suppose $x_1 < x_2$ are two zeros of $f(x)$, prove that$$
> f'\left( \frac{x_1 + 2x_2}{3} \right) < 1 - a.
> $$

*My try:*

Denote $x_3 = \dfrac{x_1 + 2x_2}{3}$. From $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = 0$, there is$$
\frac{\ln x_1 + x_1}{x_1^2} = \frac{\ln x_2 + x_2}{x_2^2} = a.
$$
Also,$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} + 1 - 2ax.
$$
Thus\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{\Longleftrightarrow}} f'(x_3) < 1 - a \Longleftrightarrow 2ax_3^2 - ax_3 - 1 > 0 \Longleftrightarrow ax_3 (2x_3 - 1) > 1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left( \frac{1}{3} ax_1 + \frac{2}{3} ax_2 \right) \left( \frac{2}{3} x_1 + \frac{4}{3} x_2 - 1 \right) > 1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left( \frac{1}{3} \frac{\ln x_1 + x_1}{x_1} + \frac{2}{3} \frac{\ln x_2 + x_2}{x_2} \right) \left( \frac{2}{3} x_1 + \frac{4}{3} x_2 - 1 \right) > 1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left( \frac{\ln x_1}{x_1} + \frac{2\ln x_2}{x_2} + 3 \right) (2x_1 + 4x_2 - 3) > 9.
\end{align*}

Then I tried to prove the last inequality for arbitrary $x_1 < x_2$, but the expression has gotten really complicated so far and the logarithm terms make it even worse to handle.

Is there a better approach to this question? Thanks in advance.

---

*Edit:*
From the comment of @MartinR and some experiment with the graph of $f$, it seems promising to prove that $0 < a < 1$ and $f'\left( \dfrac{x_1 + 2x_2}{3} \right) < 0$. Furthermore, it also seems true that $f'\left( \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \right) < 0$, which is stronger than the original inequality to be proved in that $f'$ is decreasing. So it needs proving that$$
f'\left( \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \right) = \frac{2}{x_1 + x_2} + 1 - a(x_1 + x_2) < 0.
$$
Any ideas?

Comment: Some observations: $f$ has no zeros if $a > 1$ and  a single zero at $x=1$ if $a=1$. If $0 < a < 1$ then it *seems* (from drawing some graphs) that $f'(x_3) < 0 < 1-a$.

Comment: the function given above Can only have two Zeros if $$1/8\,{\frac {1}{a} \left( 8\,\ln  \left( 1/4\,{\frac {1+\sqrt {1+8\,a}
}{a}} \right) a+\sqrt {1+8\,a}-4\,a+1 \right) }
>0$$

Comment: this is only fulfilled if $$0<a<1$$

Comment: It also seems that $f'\left( \dfrac{x_1 + 2x_2}{3} \right)$ increases for increasing $a<1$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Actually a friend of mine solved this problem and it indeed involved proving $f'\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2\right)<0$. But I forgot to post his answer and by now have also forgotten the answer.